# Inserting content inside a web-based accordion device stops it working

Tags: php, accordion

I have set up an accordion to present terms and conditions on a website which works until I attempt to pull a page from elsewhere on the server.

My coding so far is as follows:

CSS:

```
/* Accordion controls & Styles */
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Accordion:

```
<button class="accordion">Standard Terms</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/legal/inserts/standard_terms.php'); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

Standard terms page to render:

```
<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/public_header.php'); ?>

<ol>
    <h3><li>What we provide</li></h3>

</ol>


<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/public_footer.php');?>
```

Everything works as it should until I put the `<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/legal/inserts/standard_terms.php'); ?>` in if I remove it and place outside of accordion it renders fine and displays the content.

Only inside accordion does it stop everything in its tracks.

It doesn't render the rest of the page, and no errors are thrown.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please show us what the file `standard_terms.php` contains, or we won't have a clue what's going on.

Comment: enable errors, you'll see one

Comment: @MagnusEriksson added standard_terms.php

Comment: @treyBake Errors are enabled as if I change the code to different files using `<?php require(url_for('/path-to-file.php');?>` it throws the error file or directory doesn't exist.

Comment: errors don't lie - that url, is a 404

Comment: What are `public_header.php` and `public_footer.php`? You need to show us _all_ relevant code. Going by their names, I'm suspecting that those files contains the opening and closing of the document (<html><head></head><body>...</body></html>)? If that's the case, then you shouldn't load them inside another document.

Comment: They are loaded in the same document as the index file for accordion but then I was trying to load the inside the accordion as well which is what was stopping it from working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry found the answer, realised my mistake after posting the standard terms page. header and footer have already been called by previous page.